# How do I set a TimeZone for VelocityTools DateTool?

Tags: velocity

Both the [VelocityTools Tools Usage Summary](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/summary.html) and [the DateTool Javadoc](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/DateTool.html) seem to indicate a configuration mechanism for setting a TimeZone, but I simply can't discover what that is.

DateTool's timezone setter is `protected`, and I don't want repeatedly pass a TimeZone into the overloaded `format()` methods.

(VelocityTools 2.0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To pass configuration values to standard tools, you have to explicitly list them in your WEB-INF/tools.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tools>
  <toolbox scope="application">
    <tool key="date"
          class="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.DateTool"
          timezone="GMT+7"/>
    ...
  </toolbox>
  ...
</tools>
```

Please note that you can use the org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.ComparisonDateTool for the same purpose, which adds some nice date-time comparison features.

If you are not relying on the VelocityView tools loading mechanism, then it means you are putting yourself the tools in the Velocity context. If so, then the configuration values are to manually be given to the tools configure(Map). For instance:

```java
Map<String,String> config = new HashMap<>();
config.put(DateTool.TIMEZONE_KEY,"GMT+7");

DateTool date = new DateTool();
date.configure(config);

VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.put("date", date);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this still the way to configure the tools even if I'm not using Velocity as my view library, just calling it directly for some specific, limited purpose?

Comment: It depends if you're relying on the VelocityView or not. If not, then it means you are putting yourself the tools in the Velocity context. If so, then the configuration values are to be given to the tools configure(Map) method.

Comment: I'm not using `VelocityView`. I put the `DateTool` instance directly on the `VelocityContext`. I tried incantations of sending settings to that, but I didn't find any that worked. Do you have a pointer to an example? (I also assumed all the Java-recognized Timezone strings were valid. Hopefully that's true.)

Comment: I think that the following code would work: DateTool date = new DateTool(); Map config = new HashMap(); config.put("timezone","GMT+7"); tool.configure(config);

Comment: Will try. I thought I had done that (although using a named timezone string). Suggest you add that as a second answer. If it works, I'll accept it (already up-voted this one) :)

Comment: (Or, I suppose, add it to this answer.)

Comment: Ok, this works. I'm going to initiate an edit to the answer and hopefully the edit will be approved so I can accept it.

Comment: FWIW, you can always pass a `TimeZone` into `DateTool.format(..., TimeZone)` to get the right time zone. We do this in our web applications by defining a "TimeZone" bean at the application-scope that it set to `TimeZone.getDefault`, and then users can override that by setting a `TimeZone` into the session under the same key. Every call to `DateTool.format()` includes this `TimeZone`.